# How to find out which user clicked an image on my facebook website/application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-social-plugins

Say I have a facebook page/app that contains images of products that I sell. Is there a way that I can find out who the user details(facebook account) is when an image is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption I am making:

1. You are using a custom page tab
2. The page tab is an iframe
3. You have GDPed the user when they clicked on the body of the tab
4. You now know the user in the app on the tab
5. All actions by the user contain the user ID (so you can customize the experience)

Then you're already done!

C @ facebook

Answer (score 0):

you can take it by IP from access log, or you have to aim all images to php file (to log user data) before showing image

Comment: Hi Genesis, thanks for your reply. I just edited my question to clarify user to be the facebook user. IP address is useful, but I want the facebook user's account.

Comment: if you do not have their permissions and they're not accessing image from your application but just from page,  you have no chance to get their userid nor another informations

Comment: @genesis - I would not say that this is 100% correct. Even if you don't ask explicitely about permissions, the signed request contains the facebook user id - except when you already asked for permissions and the user removed them again.

Comment: depens on what the op ment with "website/application" and "page/app"...in case of a website your are right.

Comment: @Genesis, assuming a user is accessing the image from my facebook website/app, How would I log the user's facebook account name? Basically I want to log any user's facebook account who has clicked on an image on my facebook website/app.

Comment: you can't. Facebook do not send any info when redirecting user

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, the user has to connect with your app first, before you can get his user id. After you have this piece of information, it's rather simple to log all his requests.

Assuming that clicking on a product image doesn't necessarily send the user to a new URL, but maybe shows a zoomed image or shows more information, you could use Javascript to send an Ajax request to your server containing information about the product and FB user id. The URL can look something like this:

```
http://example.com/log.php?uid=xxx&product_id=ppp
```

Then server-side you'll store the information in the database.